# Список с новой строки

Tags: python

Есть данный код, переменные m и n определяют кол-во строк и столбцов, мне нужно, чтоб список выводился, согласно введенным переменным. К примеру в 3 строки и 3 столбца(квадратная матрица), без использования "Numpy"

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
arr = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        arr.append(0)
print(arr)
```

Comment: Может, в целом, не правильно понял и оформил через вложенные циклы

Comment: вы же добавляете в список и выводите весь список целиком...

Comment: а мне нужно чтоб выводило, согласно, переменным(строки и столбцы), но не понимаю как это оформить), думал что то с print делать

Comment: Да, но каждый новый список должен начинаться с новой строки)

Comment: сначала заполнить, а потом вывести его, но вывод уже n-строк и m-столбцов

Comment: проще говоря, в виде матрицы

Comment: Большое спасибо!)

Comment: пожалуйста.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
arr = []
for i in range(n):
    tmp = []
    for j in range(m):
        tmp.append(0)
    arr.append(tmp)
print(arr)
```

Либо в одну строку:

```
arr = [ [0] * m for _ in range(n) ]
```

Чтобы вывести матрицу:

```
for row in arr:
    print(*row)
```